# DatadogでJVMのヒープをサーバー毎に表示したい

Tags: java

プリセットで入っているダッシュボードだと、
各サーバーの値が一つのグラフに表示されていますが、
これを、各サーバー単位にグラフを作りたいです。
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
scopeを変更する事でやりたいことができました。